# (New to Stack Overflow) Can't get form to submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm new at this so please forgive any mistakes.. I am trying to get this form to submit but it won't return anything in the console.. is it because my entire html file is in a return statement from a js function? I assumed it would work because I imported a .css file and it translated just fine, but how do I get the submit button to return something in the console? I've attempted both querySelector and getElementbyID but when I press submit, it won't output anything.

```
import React from "react";
import './css/Contact.css';

function Contact(){
    return (
        <div className="contact-container">
          <div className="top">
            <form action="Contact" className="contactForm" id="contactForm">
            <div><input type="text" className="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"></input></div>
            <div><input type="text" className="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email"></input></div>
            <div><input type="text" className="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message"></input></div>
            <button type="submit" id = "submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="bottom">
            <h1>Get in touch!</h1>
            <h2>Hi there! We look forward to connecting with you!</h2>
            <h3>If you would like to get in touch please contact us at smartpark@sp.com or fill out the contact form displayed on your screen. </h3>
           </div>
   
          <script src="./contactDB.js"></script>   
          </div>   
          
      );
}

export default Contact;
```

### Firebase File

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  
  // Refernece contactInfo collections
  let contactInfo = firebase.database().ref("infos");
  
  // Listen for a submit
  document.querySelector("contactForm").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);
  
  function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    //   Get input Values
    let name = document.querySelector("name").value;
    let email = document.querySelector("email").value;
    let message = document.querySelector("message").value;
    console.log(name, email, message);
  
    saveContactInfo(name, email, message);
    document.querySelector("contactForm").reset();
  }
  
  // Save infos to Firebase
  function saveContactInfo(name, email, message) {
    let newContactInfo = contactInfo.push();
  
    newContactInfo.set({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message
    });
  }
```

UPDATE (fix kinda): i was coding for a javascript project when theres a react method  woops

Comment: With React and JSX you don't typically include `<script>` tags in your components

Comment: What is "action="Contact"` supposed to do?

Comment: I removed action in the end.. not supposed to be there @KonradLinkowski

Comment: "I've attempted both querySelector and getElementbyID" you are not supposed to use any of these in react

Comment: I should've been more clear.. sorry! There is an attached Firebase file to the code as well (updated)

Answer (score 0):

you should add "onSubmit" attribute to the form tag and pass the function you want to execute to it, for example:

```jsx
function Contact(){

const submitHandler = () => {
   e.preventDefault();

console.log("form submitted");
};

    return (
        <div className="contact-container">
          <div className="top">
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="contactForm" id="contactForm">
            <div><input type="text" className="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name"></input></div>
            <div><input type="text" className="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email"></input></div>
            <div><input type="text" className="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message"></input></div>
            <button type="submit" id = "submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="bottom">
            <h1>Get in touch!</h1>
            <h2>Hi there! We look forward to connecting with you!</h2>
            <h3>If you would like to get in touch please contact us at smartpark@sp.com or fill out the contact form displayed on your screen. </h3>
           </div>
   
          <script src="./contactDB.js"></script>   
          </div>   
          
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass in a call back function will be triggered onsubmit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First, to give an element a class name you have to type the attribute like this =

```
<element class=" "></element>
```

second, when you make a type="submit" button in a form when you click on it it reloads and sends the data it doesn't have time to print something in the console
the solution for this is to make the type of the button "button" or to make use the **preventDefault()** method like this:

```
const myForm = document.forms[0];

    myForm.onsubmit = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault()
    }
```

Comment: OP is using React